# Meaning of root zone

Tags: domain-name-system, root, dns-zone

In a `db.root` file, what are these lines supposed to mean?

```
$TTL 86400
. IN SOA A.ROOT-SERVERS.EDU. root.A.ROOT-SERVERS.EDU. (
        1       ; serial number (update count)
        28800   ; refresh (8 h)
        7200    ; retry (2 h)
        604800  ; expire
        10800   ; negative caching
        )
```

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1035#page-19

Comment: @Sven RFC 1035 isn't a 100% accurate reference for SOA records (see [RFC 2308](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2308#section-4)), so it's usually simpler to link to an online book. (i.e. http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/soa.html)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive bind configurations have a zone file for '.' often named db.root
The root zone consists of the top level domains such as com, net, org, arpa, us, ca, etc

TO learn more please refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server